# customizing UIStepper's layout (iOS)

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm writing a UI for an iPad app and I need to create some stepper widgets. The Traditional UIStepper looks like this:

[Value Being Changed][+][-]

And I need to make a stepper that looks like:

[-][Value Being Changed][+]

I am guessing that I need to roll my own control, but before I do that, I'd be curious to know if anyone knows if the traditional UIStepper can be changed to look like what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible using images but I doubt you would want to do that. I would roll your own UIControl. There are a few out there but they seem really old and not maintained.

Comment: Did you mean examples of custom UISteppers? I don't suppose you could point me to them, it would be a good jumping off point.

Comment: that link 404s for me :(